# Error ENOTFOUND on request to Google API Dialogflow with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, google-api, dialogflow-es

I have a Google Dialogflow application and when i do the the request to the api with a rest app (like insomnia o postman), it work. But, when i do with nodejs, it return a error:
[The "(...)" added by me]

```
> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/(...):detectIntent
> dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/(...):detectIntent:80
```

This is my code on node:

```
var datajson = '{"queryInput":{"text":{"text": "hola", "languageCode": "es"}},"queryParams":{"timeZone":"America/Santiago"}}';

var options = {
  host: 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/si(...):detectIntent',
  method: 'POST',
  json: datajson,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.c.El-3sdsa(...):detectIntent' 
  }
}

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

In Insomnia:

[image: Example of DialogFlow working on Insomnia]

[image: Example of DialogFlow working on Insomnia]

Help please?.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error occurs because you're using an invalid value for `host`, which should be:

> A domain name or IP address of the server to issue the request to.
>   Default: 'localhost'`

And you should be using `https` instead of `http` package.

```
var options = {
  host: 'dialogflow.googleapis.com',
  path: '/v2/projects/si(...):detectIntent'
}
```

And there is no `json` option in `https/http.request`, you have to use `req.write`

```
req.write(jsondata);
req.end();
```

My recommendation is to use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) which will handle a lot of things for you.

```
const request = require('request');
const options = {
  url: 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/si(...):detectIntent',
  method: 'POST',
  body: datajson,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.c.El-3sdsa(...):detectIntent' 
  }
}

request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    console.log(err, response.statusCode, body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the ENOTFOUND error code is returned simply because there's *no network connection*, and so the API server cannot be reached.

Here is an example of the actual error message returned in such a case:

```
{
  message: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, 
  reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.googleapis.com
  type: system
  errno: ENOTFOUND
  code: ENOTFOUND
  config: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    ...
  }
}
```